# android - using the tess-two library

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am following this [tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) and manage to build the library just fine.

**My State Now:**

- I take a photo, save it to the external memory (here is the directory path)

  ```
  static String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/saved_images";
  ```
- In the directory there are currently only pictures I took in jpg format.
- I can load a bitmap from the saved image.

**The problem-**

I couldn't understand how do I use this piece of code:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
// DATA_PATH = Path to the storage
// lang = for which the language data exists, usually "eng"
baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
// Eg. baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata", "eng");
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
baseApi.end();
```

- What is the `DATA_PATH` variable?
- also read something about creating a folder named tesseract  and putting there language files?

not really sure what I need to do and the tutorial doesn't explain it.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to download a traineddata file and store this in your device, try with this [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz&can=2&q=)  and copy in your device the "eng.traineddata" file. DATA_PATH is the path to the file that you added.

Comment: thanks for your answer. does the eng.traineddata file and the images files should all bein the same folder? and DATA_PATH is the path to the folder? or to the file?

Comment: DATA_PATH is the path to the file and not import where you put this.

Comment: I didnt understand where should i put the eng. Traineddata file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the file in your devices (download folder for example)

[image: File Manager]

Open the file properties in your devices:

[image: Devices properties]

and copy the path in your DATA_PATH var, for example:
/mnt/sdcard/download/eng.traineddata

the TessBaseAPI need the file for initialization.

Comment: thanks for your answer. now the init is fine, but text I am getting is a real mess.. do you have it working fine? I asked another question about it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984673/android-recognized-text-from-tess-two-library-is-wrong help would be appreciated